# How to insert a seperator string between each character in a string?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I like to write an `UPDATE` statement which should change all strings in a column to have the same value like before, but with a seperator string between each character.

Seperator: `\s*`
Before UPDATE: `abcd` 
After UPDATE: `a\s*b\s*c\s*d`

What I am missing is some string function to split a string between each character. The string concat with seperator may work with [concat_ws()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) afterwards.

Something like:

```
UPDATE tab SET col1 = concat_ws('\s*', magic_split(col1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE tab SET col1 = regexp_replace(col1, '(.)', '\1\s*');
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Just have to remove the last seperator then at the end, but that's really a minor issue. I accept your answer as soon as possible.